# Docker swarm -- container binding to ethx IP

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, vlan

I'm really a docker newbie, please forgive my lack of skills on specifying questions.

Now I've met a scene in production where I'd like to use docker swarm to connect different machines together in a docker network.

But each host machine may have multiple physical NIC(eth0, eth1, etc...), thus different IPs, and **each time I orchestrate the system, I'd like to initialize a new network for each container, letting the container use a particular IP among NIC's IP. But each container using the IP of each NIC, not under docker0.**

I've read the [doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#docker-and-iptables) on docker **17.06ce** mentioning using `DOCKER-USER` flag, but I can't quite understand that.

Using host network is not the best option for me because that will occupy the port globally.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you think in network-mode=host? With that the container gets and share the same interfaces as the host. *With the network set to host a container will share the host’s network stack and all interfaces from the host will be available to the container.* https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#example

Comment: @Robert
Thanks for your advice, but using host network isn't the best option for me, because in that way the container will occupy some port globally.
I'm trying to modify `iptables` manually on `DOCKER-USER` in filter table. But I'm not sure how to write the rules.